# Dequeue Azure Storage queue from Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I've been looking for examples to easily dequeue an Azure Storage queue the same way you can enqueue an item (by injecting IAsyncCollector in the Run method). but alas, no success.
The only things I've found are enqueueing items or reacting to items being added to a queue.

There is an app running on my local server that will periodically call the function (and keeps calling till the queue is empty) to get the items of the queue. I want to do this using an Azure function.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this doc about ICollector:[ICollector with Azure Storage Queue](http://Using%20ICollector%20with%20Azure%20Storage%20Queue).

> ICollector and IAsyncCollector can be used as parameter types for Storage Queue output bindings.

For now azure function binding only supports output binding to write messages to a queue. Or You could use queue trigger to retrieve message if you don't need to call it with HTTP request.

If you have to use HTTP request, suppose you have to create a HTTP trigger function, then retrieve and delete the queue to implement a dequeue action like the below code.

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        // Parse the connection string and return a reference to the storage account.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage"));
        CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

        // Retrieve a reference to a queue
        CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("myqueue");

        // Async dequeue the message
        CloudQueueMessage retrievedMessage = await queue.GetMessageAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Retrieved message with content '{0}'", retrievedMessage.AsString);

        //Process the message in less than 30 seconds, and then delete the message
        await queue.DeleteMessageAsync(retrievedMessage);

        return  (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(retrievedMessage.AsString);

    }
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the information. I thought the process of dequeueing would be as easy as queueing.

Comment: It’s partially because the majority of the time you really want to trigger on a queue message and not pull in separate from trigger. Any details on why you prefer pulling messages In code instead of trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a webhook function that your app calls then within the function you can dequeue items as necessary using the standard storage queue api for whatever language you use.

Comment: When you add items to a queue, you can bind an IAsyncCollector and use that instance to insert data. I thought that the same could be done for dequeueing a queue. But apparently not. I will have to go with the solution you and @GeorgeChen proposed