# Azure Storage Queue 405 Error message when invoking Dequeue message via SDK

Tags: azure-storage

I have code that uses the .NET SDK to dequeue messages from an Azure Storage Queue.  This works fine when running locally in the debugger.  However when I run in a Kubernetes Cluster I am getting a HTTP 405 Error - "The resource doesn't support the specified http verb". Any ideas on why this particular error message would be thrown by the SDK?  It obviously has to be using the correct HTTP verb.

Comment: can you please provide the code that you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below workarounds:

Sometimes it may be due to small changes  that this error can occur.

1. Please check if you are  passing name of the queue and the other
   params  of the queue correctly that you are trying to dequeue.
2. Also try to ***`allow CORS`*** in your application

*Web.config:*

```
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
          <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
          </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
```

3. The issue maybe with http verb , as azure allows https
   requests.Please check and try to change from http to https rquests.
4. Some times it may occur by using  POST method .

Try retrieve the queue  and delete the queue to implement a dequeue action like the below code from [c#- Dequeue - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58155485/dequeue-azure-storage-queue-from-azure-function)

```
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        // Parse the connection string and return a reference to the storage account.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage"));
        CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

        // Retrieve a reference to a queue
        CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("myqueue");

        // Async dequeue the message
        CloudQueueMessage retrievedMessage = await queue.GetMessageAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Retrieved message with content '{0}'", retrievedMessage.AsString);

        //Process the message in less than 30 seconds, and then delete the message
        await queue.DeleteMessageAsync(retrievedMessage);

        return  (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(retrievedMessage.AsString);

    }
```

Similar microsoft doc- [dequeue-messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-tutorial-queues?tabs=dotnet%2Cenvironment-variable-windows#dequeue-messages) using  `ReceiveMessagesAsync`, retrieve only the next messages in the queue. After the message is received, delete it from the queue by calling `DeleteMessageAsync`.

5. You can check few causes here > [***HTTP Error 405.0***  (IIS)
   websites  | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/http-error-405-website)

This problem can occur if the user has installed the IIS feature with all options ticked, including the `"WebDAV Publishing"`.So remove the WebDAV Publishing feature

**Reference:**

1. [c# - Azure ASP Web API error 405 method not allowed - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44776644/azure-asp-web-api-error-405-method-not-allowed#:%7E:text=Simply%20change%20the%20http%20to%20https%20in%20the,405%20-%20The%20request%20could%20not%20be%20completed.)